# setting up multiple catchall accounts with Gsuite

Tags: catch-all

I have a Gsuite account and a primary domain added to the same. I also have a catchall email account associated with this domain. Now I need to set up another catchall account to segregate my production and testing environment. from what I have explored so far, one domain can only be associated with one catachall account. Here's what I think are the options left for me.

1. Buy another domain, add the same to Gsuite account, and configure the catchall account for the new domain.

My only question is if I can avoid buying a new domain altogether? are there any other alternatives I can explore?

-Prasad

Comment: After some analysis, I kind of concluded that we can not set multiple primary domains with a single G Suite account. So ended up creating another Gsuite account and set up the catachall for the same. Also, I did not have to buy the sub domain.